# How to get value of a input field in jsoup in java?

Tags: java, android, jsoup, html-parsing

I want to scrap the value entered in a web page in input field using JSOUP in Java. The value in the input field is already added by the server.

[image: Here is the web page]

In JavaScript, we use to select the element by id and then easily get the value using the `.value` as shown in the picture below.

[image: JavaScript data scrapping demonstration]

This is how the HTML looks like

[image: HTML looks like]

I wanna know how to do this with JSOUP and Java.

Comment: How is the value preset by the server? If the text dos not appear as value of the input, where does it come from?

Comment: You "want to scrap the value entered in a web page in input field". This can not be done with JSoup, because JSoup is parsing HTML that is generated and does not involve any user interaction (when web scraping, your scrapper program is the user!).

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the input HTML looks like this

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
        SSID:<br>
        <input id="input_wifi_ssid" type="text" value="SSID-value"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This will extract and print that you want

```
String input = "<html><body><form action=\"/action_page.php\">SSID:<br>"
    + "<input id=\"input_wifi_ssid\" type=\"text\" value=\"SSID-value\"><br>"
    + "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"></form></body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);
Element elem = doc.getElementById("input_wifi_ssid");
System.out.println(elem.attr("value"));
```

Output

```
SSID-value
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: There is actually no value attribute in the HTML for input tag.

Comment: @an0nh4x0r it's just an example. You don't give any HTML sample with your post. Edit your question with a HTML sample and I'll modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: I edited the post and included the HTML screenshot of that particular section.

Comment: @an0nh4x0r, nah that's not helpful. You just screened your initial static HTML page source. There is no value populated, so nothing to parse. Jsoup works with static data. In your example at the end of this page you must be have a button that performs submit, so values populated and page submitted to the server. That HTML can be parsed.